# Confusing error from structured binding declaration

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, tuples

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main() {

  vector<vector<int>> points = {{3, 12}, {-2, 5}, {-4, 1}};
  vector<tuple<int, int, int>> edges;
  for (int u = 0; u < points.size(); ++u) {
    for (int v = u + 1; v < points.size(); ++v) {
      edges.emplace_back(u, v,
                         abs(points[v][0] - points[u][0]) +
                             abs(points[v][1] - points[u][1]));
    }
  }
  sort(begin(edges), end(edges),
       [](const auto &a, const auto &b) { return get<2>(a) < get<2>(b); });
  int result = 0;
  for (const auto &[u, v, val] : edges) {
    result += val;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

compile with `g++ -std=c++17 main.cc`

got following confused ERROR:

> main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> main.cc:20:20: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
>
> for (const auto &[u, v, val] : edges) {
> ^ main.cc:20:20: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘[’ token
>
> main.cc:20:21: error: ‘u’ was not declared in this scope
>
> for (const auto &[u, v, val] : edges) {
> ^ main.cc:20:24: error: ‘v’ was not declared in this scope
>
> for (const auto &[u, v, val] : edges) {
> ^ main.cc:20:27: error: ‘val’ was not declared in this scope
>
> for (const auto &[u, v, val] : edges) {
> ^ main.cc: In lambda function:
>
> main.cc:20:32: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘:’ token
>
> for (const auto &[u, v, val] : edges) {
> ^ main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> main.cc:20:32: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘:’ token
>
> main.cc:20:32: error: expected primary-expression before ‘:’ token
>
> main.cc:20:32: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘:’ token
>
> main.cc:20:32: error: expected primary-expression before ‘:’ token

How to fix this error?
NOTE:gcc version 5.4.0

Comment: does gcc 5.4.0 supports `C++17`?

Comment: Structured binding support added in GCC 7. Here is the reference: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx17

Comment: Maybe replace `for (const auto &[u, v, val] : edges)` with `for (const auto &val : edges)`

Comment: Adding line-numbers would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is well-formed in C++17, but your GCC version is too old to support C++17:s structured bindings.

As specified in [C++ Standards Support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html), *Structured Bindings* ([P0283R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0283r2.html)) was implemented for GCC 7, and is thus not (fully) available in the by now ancient GCC 5.4.

We may verify this by noting that your program compiles for GCC 7.1 ([DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/h3pAfGvo0JUbsI3D)), whereas is does not compile for GCC 6.3 ([DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3HjSsGgcOIRCWMsf)).